# Assign BASH variable from file with specific criteria

Tags: bash, shell, awk

A config file that the last line contains data that I want to assign everything to the RIGHT of the = sign into a variable that I can display and call later in the script.

Example:  `/path/to/magic.conf`:

```
foo
bar
ThisOption=foo.bar.address:location.555
```

What would be the best method in a bash shell script to read the last line of the file and assign everything to the right of the equal sign?  In this case, `foo.bar.address:location.555`.

The last line always has what I want to target and there will only ever be a single = sign in the file that happens to be the last line.

Google and searching here yielded many close but non-relative results with using sed/awk but I couldn't come up with exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are the line numbers actually in the file?  If not, don't include them in the question; we can most of us count to 'many' (you know: zero, one, many).

Comment: In a perfect world, disregarding what you currently believe to be true for all files, would this look for the option by name (because you care about that specific option, regardless of position) or by file position (because you care about the last defined option in a file, regardless of name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
variable=$(sed -n 's/^ThisOption=//p' /path/to/magic.conf)
echo "The option is: $variable")
```

This works by finding and removing the `ThisOption=` marker at the start of the line, and `p`rinting the result.

Comment: You could also use `sed -n '$s/^[^=]*=//' "$configfile"` to read the last line and deal with an arbitrary variable name before the equals sign.

Comment: This would require that you know what the "ThisOption" be. The wording of the question seems to imply that you would not have the luxury of knowing this, only that the assignment statement would happen on the last line of the file.

Comment: I inferred that the config file format was sane, and that the extra information was to try to make the task easier

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT**: This method absolutely requires that the file be trusted 100%. As mentioned in the comments, anytime you "eval" code without any sanitization there are grave risks (a la "rm -rf /" magnitude - don't run that...)

Pure, simple bash. (well...using the tail utility :-) )
The advantage of this method, is that it only requires you to know that it will be the last line of the file, it does not require you to know any information about that line (such as what the variable to the left of the = sign will be - information that you'd need in order to use the sed option)

```
assignment_line=$(tail -n 1 /path/to/magic.conf)
eval ${assignment_line}
var_name=${assignment_line%%=*}
var_to_give_that_value=${!var_name}
```

Of course, if the var that you want to have the value is the one that is listed on the left side of the "=" in the file then you can skip the last assignment and just use "${!var_name}" wherever you need it.

Comment: Using `eval` works, but requires you to trust that the config file does not contain anything malicious (such as: `ThisOption=$(rm -fr $HOME &; echo foo.bar.address:location.555)` — do not play with fire if experimenting!).

Comment: Valid. Added a edit, as you are correct, this is worth stating explicitly in the answer.